# Number of ways getting sum K with a pair of 6sided dices.

Tags: sum, dynamic-programming

Given a of 6sided pair of dices, in how many ways can I get sum K.

Can someone give a detailed explanation to me how to use dynamic programming to solve this problem. 
I have done reading on it but still hard to understand [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dice-throw-problem/)

Comment: What is the upper limit of K ?

Comment: @MukitChowdhury upper limit is 100

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. Would you please explain it more ? 

Is it like this... I've been given two dice of six side each. I've to make K. How many ways I can do that ??? Is it the problem ?

Comment: @MukitChowdhury yes. That is I exactly what I mean.

Comment: Should I throw two dice at a same time ? Can I throw dice more than one time ? Would you please give me the actual problem link ?

Comment: @MukitChowdhury yes, you can throw more than one time. Like if we want to make K=7, then for example 1+6, 2+5, 3+4, 2+5, 3+3+1 are 5 different ways to make 7.

Comment: Then 1+1+1+1+1+1+1=7 is also a way, right ?

Comment: @MukitChowdhury yes. As long as you can get 7 with it

Comment: Then it is too easy. You have no need of counting two dice. If both dice is drawn at a same time and it's not possible to draw a single dice, then you should count two dice. Otherwise you don't need. Have you understood the reason ?